# Конвертация ActiveRecord

Tags: php, ооп, yii2, activerecord

У меня есть такая иерархия классов

```
class Question extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {/** Implementation **/}
class TextQuestion extends Question {/** Implementation **/}
class SumQuestion extends Question {/** Implementation **/}
```

Есть ли возможность преобразовать объект `Question` в `TextQuestion` или `SumQuestion`?

Примитивный пример

```
$question = new Question();
$sum = (SumQuestion)$question;
```

Первая идея которая пришла в голову это перебросить атрибуты, но возможно есть более правильное решение

```
$question = new Question();
$sum = new SumQuestion();
$sum->setAttributes($question->getAttributes());
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: вы не могли бы уточнить для чего это вам необходимо?

Comment: От клиента приходит некий секрет, тип ответа изначально не знаю. Поэтому выборка идет через модель Question, а затем по полю тип нужно конвертировать объект в нужный.

Comment: Мда уточнение ещё больше запутало нас.

Comment: Попробую еще раз ), вкратце - когда клиент отвечает на вопрос то на сервер идет запрос с ответом и неким секретным кодом по которому идет поиск вопроса в базе. Тип вопроса с клиента не приходит, поэтому нужно сначала выбрать данные из базы через модель  Question по секретному ключу, а затем конвертировать ее в нужный тип чтобы было необходимое поведение и т.д.

Comment: Ребята гляньте решение, возможно у кого-то вызовет сомнения

Comment: Вы привели пример класической фабрики. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал примерно таким образом, возможно есть какие-то подводные камни но их пока не выявил.

```
class Question extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {

     public function convert() {
         // Тут идет получение объекта по типу из фабрики, но для ясности указал явный тип
         $model = new SumQuestion();
         $model->setOldAttributes($this->getOldAttributes());
         // Перенимаем атрибуты 
         $model->setAttributes($this->getAttributes(), false);
         // Вызываем afterFind событие для того чтобы модель думала что ее выбрали из базы
         $model->afterFind();

         return $model;
    }
}

$question = Question::find()
            ->where(['secret' => $secret])
            ->one();
$converted = $question->convert();
```